# How to nicely print Buffer in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have a **Buffer**.

**Question 1**

How can I print out all byte inside one by one?

**Question 2**

How can I control the format of the printing?

For example, if I have a buffer like `33 33 33 33 33 33 14 40` (every byte is in HEX format), how can I print it as `\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x14\x40`?

Comment: What about `Buffer.output_buffer stdout buf` ([documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Buffer.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply an imperative function `f` to every byte in a buffer `b`, you can use `String.iter f (Buffer.contents b)`.

To print a value with a desired format, you can use `Printf.printf`.

To get the integer value of a byte in a string you can use `Char.code`.

As a side comment, many of your recent questions could be answered extremely quickly by reading through the OCaml standard library documentation. I think this would be a good thing for you to do. There's not a lot of deep intellectual content, it's just something you should know about as an OCaml programmer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have.

Comment: jeffrey, could you please tell me if i can use `Printf.printf "\\x%X" i` to print i. if i is 22, it is printed as `\x16`; but if i is 1, then it will print out `\x1', but I wish for `\x01` for consistant two position filled, what should I do? is this the only way: `if i < 16 then Printf.printf "\\x0%X" i else Printf.printf "\\x%X" i`?

Comment: Yu can use `"\\x%2.2X"` if I understand what you want. Something else to read through at some point is `printf()` docs for C :-)